# PDO with Drupal 7?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, pdo, drupal-7

I don't want to use drupal db_ rules.. I'd rather use my own pdo techniques for database queries and updates etc.. But I've managed to be able to get pdo to work, the only issue is that I have to use a connect on every custom page, some users in my community can edit the pages and will be able to see the connection information.. require & require_once do not seem to work.

Has anyone else had this issue and knows how to avoid it?

Comment: If you include your connection code in a custom module, you should be able to avoid this issue.

Comment: So I need to learn how to create a custom module and I'll be fine?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Drupal's DB functions? What's wrong with them? Having your own PDO code means you'll have at least two DB connections for every page load, which will have a negative impact on performance and scalability of your site.

Comment: Why bother with a framework at all if you're going to spend your time working out how not to use the features it offers? You understand that internally Drupal will most certainly still be using its own API, so whatever benefits you're trying to realise are going to be at the surface only? If you're daunted by learning the Drupal DB API, don't be - it's very easy, and actually an improvement over plain 'ol PDO when used in a Drupal site. Just try to create a sorted table or numbered pages without it and you'll see what I mean. Forcing yourself to use PDO is a very strange approach, I must say.

Comment: I only prefer to use PDO because like you say, it's what I'm most used to. I cannot see me able to do the same problem solving with their approach. I like their content management but when it comes to custom pages I really prefer my own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own module and use the init hook:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7

```
function yourmodulename_init() {
  // This code will be executed on every page
}
```

However you should try to use the drupal database mechanics as it comes with a lot of best practices and powerful tools. E.g. views integration:

https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, [`Database::getConnection`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/Database::getConnection/7) allows you to retrieve [`DatabaseConnection`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/class/DatabaseConnection/7) objects for all configured databases. And `DatabaseConnection` extends [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) so if your really want to bypass Drupal's Database API (which is itself based on PDO and either re-use or extends PDO classes all over the place), you can use it as you would use your own `PDO` object.

But if user of your community are able to edit your custom page, I'm guessing that your are actually embedding PHP code inside Drupal nodes using the PHP filter. Which is itself a very bad idea (worse than ignoring Drupal's Database API). You should instead consider [writing custom modules](https://drupal.org/node/361112) tailored for your needs.